# Git :: Split multi-module project into 2 modules and keep history

Tags: git, git-submodules

Currently we do have one large project, constisting of modules **A,B,C,D,E**. These modules are located within same project repository on **github**, but in different folders - each module in it's own folder. Project is managed bt Maven, if that matters.

Recently we decided to split the project in two different instances - **P1** and **P2**, so they will reside in different repositories. **P1** should hold modules **A,C,D** and project **P2** should hold **B,E**.

So now we're thinking that we have at least 4 options:

- Leave the project as it is now. Add corresponding Git modules to **P1** and **P2**, so every module will point to appropriate folder in *parent* project This will preserve the history for sure (I think so at least).
- Create repository for **P1**, check-in things into it. Then move modules **B,E** to folder **client**, and then create import the folder **client** as module into **P2** repo. I don't know is it possible at all, but it also should preserve history.
- Checkin everything into **P1** and **P2**, then remove modules **B,E** from **P1**, and modules **A,C,D** from **P2**. Then add **P2** as git module to **P1**. This should preserve history, but actually too much of it - so module **P2** will contain everything from **P1** up to the moment of diverging. We'd like to avoid this, if possible.
- And finally, simply check it everything as new project, starting from scratch.

Personally I'd prefer first option, but not sure if that is possible at all - e.g, add dependency of subfolder of a foreign project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a new repo for each submodule then you should look at [git-subtree](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree). Use the `split` options to create new branches with just the history of your sub-folders. Then you can `push` those to new remotes as the `master` branch.

Hit me up if you need specifics on usage.